# How to return boost::fusion::vector<x,y,z> elements to add to a std::array<boost::fusion::vector<x,y,z>>?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I have a `std::array` and a `boost::fusion::vector<X, Y>` which I want to pass in to `func1()`. This function will add a `boost::fusion::vector<X, Y>` instance to each `std::array` element.

**I have to use `fusion::fold()` so that I can add the correct number of elements to the `fusion::vector<X,Y>`, right?**

So I currently have something like this:

```
void func1(){
    boost::fusion::vector<X,Y> my_vec;
    std::array<boost::fusion::vector<X,Y> > my_array[10];
    func2(my_vec, my_array);
}

void func2(boost::fusion::vector<X,Y> my_vec, std::array<boost::fusion::vector<X,Y> > my_array){

    //THIS IS THE PART I AM UNSURE ABOUT
    for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
        //The first two parameters aren't so important- just included to show the idea
        my_array[k] = boost::fusion::fold(my_vec, 1, some_struct);
    }
}

//This part is irrelevant
struct some_struct
{
    typedef int result_type;

    template<typename T>
    int operator()(int x, T& t) const
    {
        t = something(x);
        //Not sure if this part needs to return a boost::fusion::vector<X, Y>
        return x;
    }
};
```

The part I am unsure about is how to use the signature of `my_vec` in order to create multiple `boost::fusion::vector<X,Y>` instances and return them back so that I can add to the array in `func2()`.

Could somebody please advise?

EDIT - Just spotted I got the first parameter for `fold()` wrong, have amended my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understood your question really well so first let's explain what [fold](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/fold.html) is to try to clarify.

In general (not just for fusion) "folding" a function taking two parameters is applying it to each and every element of the vector and to the result of the application of the function to the previous element of the vector. The first element is being given the initial value.

So if I define the function to fold as `A f(A, B)`, the folding of this function will be equivalent to (for 4 elements):

```
f(f(f(f(A_initial_value, B_0), B_1), B_2), B_3);
```

(capitalized prefix is there just to enforce type)

Now, more precisely fusion [fold](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/fold.html). It will fold the function on all the elements inside the `boost::fusion::vector<>`. As a `boost::fusion::vector<X, Y>` is equivalent to a `std::tuple<X,Y>` it will call `f` on different types:

```
A_final_value = f(A_initial_value, X_value), Y_value);
```

So, when you do:

```
my_array[k] = boost::fusion::fold(my_vec, 1, some_struct);
```

`my_array[k]` will receive an numeric value, and that won't compile since you've defined it as `fusion::vector<X,Y>`

So having trying to clarify `fold`, I would say **no** to your question, but I admit that I do not understand what you mean by "add the correct number of elements to the `fusion::vector<X,Y>`".

EDIT: Updating according what've been said in comment.
The goal isto generate a fibonacci sequence in your `std::array<fusion::vector<int, int, int, int>>` such as walking each `vector` of the `array` will give the fibonacci in the right order.

Using `fusion` you have to pass a state while iterating through the elements of the `vector` and so `fold`was a good choice.

Here is my suggestion for this (but starting the fibonacci sequence at the second element and not the first, cause I didn't bother to handle the special case... sorry :) ):

```
template <typename Value>
struct Generator
{
  // Easier to read and mandatory for fold
  typedef typename std::tuple<Value, Value> result_type;

  // The function that generate the fibonacci and update the Value  
  result_type operator()(result_type previous, Value& elem) const
  {
    elem = std::get<0>(previous) + std::get<1>(previous);
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<1>(previous), elem);
  }
};

// Use template to be a bit more generic on array size and vector type
template <typename Vector, size_t array_size, typename Value>
void func2(std::array<Vector, array_size>& array, std::tuple<Value, Value> init)
{
  // The state that will be fed across the fold function
  auto previous = init;
  for (auto& vect: array)
  {        
    // Generate the fibonnaci value for every element of the vector starting
    // from where the state is. The return value of fold is the new state
    previous = boost::fusion::fold(vect, previous, Generator<Value>());
  }
}

// Tool to print the vector
struct Printer
{
  template <typename Elem>
  void operator()(const Elem& elem) const
  {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
};

// Use template to be a bit more generic on array size and vector type
template <typename Vector, size_t array_size, typename Value>
void func1(std::tuple<Value, Value> init)
{    
  // Create the vector
  std::array<Vector, array_size> array;

  // FIll it with fibonacci
  func2(array, init);

  // Print it
  for (auto vect: array)
  {        
    boost::fusion::for_each(vect, Printer());
  }   
}
```

http://rextester.com/XCXYX58360

Comment: I would like to create numerous fusion::vector<X,Y>s and each of these instances should be stored in the std::array. Does this help?

Comment: @user3125975 yes and no. It's basically what you're doing here `std::array<boost::fusion::vector<X,Y> > my_array[10];`, so I assume you want to initialize them a specific way. Why no just `my_array[k] = something()` where `something`is the function returning one `fusion::vector` that you're calling in `somestruct` ?

Comment: How does something() know how many elements to put in the vector? It needs to "see" the format of my_vec?

Comment: @user3125975 Your `fusion::vector` size is defined at compile time. If it can vary, it will be at compile time. To handle this, either you take the `fusion::vector` type as template parameter, either your use a variadic template. But what you plan to do with `something` ? A generic initializer seems a bit odd in this context... You have alreay [`make_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/generation/functions/make_vector.html) for this.

Comment: I want to store the fibonnaci sequence. So the first 4 numbers would go in the vector in std::array element [0] and then the next 4 fibonnaci numbers go in a fusion vector and that fusion vector goes in to the std::array element [1] etc..... so each of the new fusion vectors has to be "aware" of the contents which were placed in the previous fusion vector?

Comment: Ok, it is a lot clearer. I do not see why you want to split everything in 4 values tuples but here's something that does almost what you want (starting at the second value of the fibonacci sequence not the first) using `fold` (to pass the fibonacci state across the elements): http://rextester.com/XCXYX58360

Comment: @user3125975 I've updated my answer according to this.